# Use of "this" and "super" to invoke constructors

Tags: java, constructor, this

I have two questions about the use of "this" and "super" respectively inside a constructor.

If an overloaded constructor is invoked from another constructor, is it mandatory that the invocation statement **this(......)** be the first in it? I heard that otherwise there will be a compiler error.

If a base class constructor is invoked from inside a derived class contructor, it is advisable (not mandatory) that the invocation statement **super(.....)** be the first in it? I heard that otherwise the compiler will insert a default **super()** with no arguments and make it the first statement.

If the above concepts are true, it seems the compiler is more stringent on "this" and flexible on "super".

Comment: You must have an empty object of this class before you can execute any constructor populating or doing something with the emerging object. You must have a parent class object (at least the empty one) before you continue with the construction of the base class. I see no difference in the philosophy or mechanics.

Comment: You can easily test this out by writing a small piece of code to verify the things you've heard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a `this(...);` call for one constructor to call another, it must appear first in the body.

If there is a `super(...);` call for a constructor to call the superclass's constructor, it must also appear first in the body.  (You can't include some other statements and then call `super(...)`.)  So this really isn't any more flexible than the rules for `this(...)`.  If there's no `super(...)` at all, and no `this(...)`, then there's an implicit `super()`, with no arguments, inserted as the first statement of the body.  If the superclass defines constructors but doesn't define a no-argument constructor, then subclass constructor **must** start with a `super(...)` call [or `this(...)`], or else the compiler will give you an error:

```
public class Class1 {
    public Class1(int arg) { ... }
    public Class1(String arg) { ... }
}

public class Class2 {
    public Class2() {
        // The body MUST start with this "super" statement:
        super(<something>);
        // where the argument can be converted to an int or String, or else it's
        // an error!  (Exception: it can start with a this() to call another constructor
        // defined for Class2.)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If an overloaded constructor is invoked from another constructor, is it mandatory that the "this" statement be the first in it? I heard that otherwise there will be a compiler error.

if you try to initialize object fields with other constructor and you invoke it via `this(...)` then it needs to be first statement of calling constructor

> If a base class constructor is invoked from inside a derived class contructor, it is advisable (not mandatory) that the "super" statement be the first in it? I heard that otherwise the compiler will insert super() and make it the first statement.

Yes

> If the above concepts are true, it seems the compiler is more stringent on "this" and flexible on "super".

while creating an instance of child class you are going to initialize super class's fields anyhow so it needs a call to default constructor implicitly

Answer (score 2):

The first statement of any constructor is always `super()` (implicitly); *unless* you make the first line an explicit call to a `super()` constructor **or** to a `this()` constructor.

This is covered by [JLS-8.8.9. Default Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) which says (in part)

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is implicitly declared.
>
> If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the default constructor has an empty body. Otherwise, the default constructor simply invokes the superclass constructor with no arguments.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if a default constructor is implicitly declared but the superclass does not have an accessible constructor ([§6.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6)) that takes no arguments and has no throws clause.**